# Emscripten C struck at function socket()

Tags: javascript, c, sockets, webassembly, emscripten

In the below code, program execution is getting struck after calling the socket() function.

Could anyone find the cause and solution for this problem?

**Update: (To reproduce the issue) Here I have executed the below code without emscripten with GCC, and it is working without any issue but not working after compiling to emscripten web assembly**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define VNC_BASE 8080
#define DEFAULT_DISPLAY ":10"

int accept_connection (int port)
{
    int bound;
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    int on = 1;
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sin.sin_port = htons (/*VNC_BASE + port*/8080);

    printf("In\n"); // <-- Getting printed
    
    bound = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);  // <-- Getting struck

    printf("Out : %d\n", bound);  // <-- Not Getting printed

    if (bound < 0)
    {
        perror ("socket");
        exit (1);
    }

    setsockopt (bound, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof (on));

    if (bind (bound, (struct sockaddr *) &sin,
              sizeof (struct sockaddr_in))) {
        perror ("bind");
        exit (1);
    }

    int lStatus = listen (bound, 1);

    printf("Listen status : %d\n", lStatus);

    sock = accept (bound, NULL, 0);

    printf("Accept status : %d\n", sock);

    close (bound);
    return sock;
}

int main()
{
    int clientw = accept_connection (10);
    printf("Client w : %d\n", clientw);
}
```

Use the below command to compile the code to webassembly

```
emcc ./test.c -s WASM=1 -o ./test.js -lwebsocket.js -s PROXY_POSIX_SOCKETS=1 -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -s PROXY_TO_PTHREAD=1
```

I have made this repo to reproduce the issue :
https://github.com/AithaTarun/Webassembly/tree/main

**Expected to create a server process on port 8080 with emscripten support**

Comment: I don't know anything about emscripten, but at first glance, your C code looks good. Have you tried building it in a pure C environment (no emscripten, no javascript) to see if it still gets stuck on the socker() call?

Comment: Ha yes, I have tried that, it is working without any issues if I built the code and executed it with GCC.

Comment: There is no loop in this code, so it can't get stuck in an infinite loop on `socket()`. Is `accept_connection()` being called in a loop? Please provide a [mcve]. On a side note, `if (bind (...))` should be `if (bind (...) < 0)`. And, you are not checking `listen()` or `accept()` for failure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Remy, Sorry it is not stuck in an infinite loop, the programming is not getting executed further after the socket() method is called, also, thanks for the side note. Also, I have updated the question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: So you mean to say the `socket` call is blocking execution?

Comment: Yes autistic, it is blocking the further execution of the script.